# HTML5 Canvas base64 to image base64_decode corrupted in Safari

Tags: php, html, canvas, safari, konvajs

Upon saving base64 code to server but for some reason safari corrupts the image.
[image]

But when copying the base64 code outputted into the browser or debug bar the image works fine.

The PHP code i am using is:

```
function base64ToImage($imageData){

            $fileName = 'uploaded_' . uniqid();

            $data = explode( ',', $imageData );
            $imageData = base64_decode( $data[ 1 ] );

            $path = '/templates/' . $_POST['templateName'] . '/images/';

            file_put_contents($path . $fileName . '.jpg', $imageData);              

            return $fileName;
        }
```

Comment: `/` is a part of the Base64 character set, you shouldn't be doing that `explode()` with it.

Comment: Thanks @Narf I have corrected that

Comment: I have also found it only happens server side, not locally.

Comment: Any reason you don't send it as a multipart (from a Blob) instead of sending as a b64 string? Also, what are the `post_max_size` and alike on your server?

Comment: Hi @Kaiido. post_max_size is 8M. The b64 string is from HTML5 canvas